# Is the Hobbit diet based on Full English breakfast and Tea?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit, food

There are 3 notable meals described occurring in the Shire, or its vicinity in *The Hobbit* and *Lord of The Rings*:

During the “unexpected party”, Bilbo *exhausts his larder* putting out cakes, buttered scones, biscuits, seed-cake, eggs, cold chicken, pickles, coffee, tea, and beer. The dwarves call for “mince pies, pork pies, raspberry jam, apple tart, and salad”, but it is not said that he has that. Only Gandalf “seems to know” what is in his larder.

At Bilbo’s one-hundred eleventh birthday party the food is said to be “rich, abundant, varied…”, but no food is described in particular.

Years later, at Farmer Maggots, Frodo and Sam gorge on a Mushroom and Bacon casserole.

Bilbo ate only the food “fit to eat” after the Trolls were killed -- bread, cheese, and bacon.

The meals at Beorn’s lodge are consumed with relish, but do not count, for obvious reasons.

Is the diet of the Shire Hobbits based on the “Full English” breakfast and High [Tea](http://www.afternoontea.co.uk/information/what-is-high-tea/)? Do they eat the way Americans seem to imagine the English to eat all day long?

For questions on what [Tea](http://www.afternoontea.co.uk/information/what-is-high-tea/) is, please click on the link.

Comment: None of those foods would be found in an English breakfast, other than bacon.

Comment: @OrangeDog ...and Tea.

Comment: There's also the rabbit stew (could use some taters) that Sam cooks in Ithilien; while not actually in the Shire, the inference seems to be that he's doing his very best there to make something you might find in the Shire.

Comment: I don't think we hear of hobbits eating fried eggs, toast, baked beans, or fried/grilled tomatoes, and there are plenty of things we do hear about that aren't in the full English breakfast:  cheese, buttered scones, biscuits, seed-cake, cold chicken, pickles, etc.  The diet is clearly English, but not limited to the full English breakfast.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or role-playing as wizards ;-) **This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36249/discussion-on-question-by-gandalf-is-the-hobbit-diet-based-on-full-english-break)**, where you can continue as long as you like. I tried to leave all comments that bear directly on the question; please ping me if you think I've deleted anything I shouldn't have.

Comment: @WadCheber And Tea. Why do people keep missing that? It was breakfast and Tea, which is eaten at 4 in the afternoon, or at least my family did.

Comment: @Gandalf fair enough - I just wonder where these Americans visited to get that impression. Mind you, don't all Americans eat burgers made of pizza with hotdogs in the crust? ;)

Comment: @Gandalf - Ah.  The problem is that **in Britain, "tea" is both a beverage AND a meal.  In the US, "tea" is simply what you get when you put tea leaves in water - i.e., the beverage, not the meal**.  Editing to explain that you mean the MEAL known as "tea" would go a long way towards avoiding confusion.

Comment: In other words, to everyone who isn't in Britain, you seem to be asking whether hobbits eat nothing but eggs, toast, grilled tomatoes and mushrooms, baked beans, bacon and sausage, as well as drinking tea.

Comment: @WadCheber That's why it was Capitalized.

Comment: Capitalizing doesn't make it any clearer to an American.  I've spent plenty of time in Britain, and I lived in Ireland for a year, but even I saw "Tea" as "hot water, tea leaves, sugar, and milk".  We simply don't think of food when we see that word, capitalized or not. (on a side note, for half of the US, "Tea" means "tea leaves, cold water, sugar, and ice")

Comment: @WadCheber Tea includes cakes, scones, biscuits, and tea.

Comment: Let's go to chat.  http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36249/discussion-on-question-by-gandalf-is-the-hobbit-diet-based-on-full-english-break

Comment: @WadCheber I included a link to help clear up the confusion over "What is Tea?"

Comment: @WadCheber I'm English, and I have exactly your interpretation. To me "English Breakfast" means the food items you mentioned, and the word tea (whether or not capitalised), particularly when used in the same sentence as "English Breakfast", means the beverage. The use of the word tea to mean a meal is a regional thing - in London, where I'm from, it is never used like that. I'm confused by the OP's use of the phrase "English Breakfast" because none of the examples given are anything like english breakfast.

Comment: @WadCheber I'm also fairly certain that almost all British people, regardless of region, would read "English Breakfast and Tea" and assume you mean the drink, because of the context.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's hard to answer this beyond what was included in the question; in their preferred environment, hobbits eat food that would be commensurate with traditional English meals. This is demonstrably true, by numerous example.

About the best I can do is say that this was almost certainly not by accident; Tolkien was very clear in his letters that the hobbits are based on England; for example (bold is my emphasis, italic is Tolkien's):

> [N]o one would have said 'The Shire is not far from North Oxford'. It is in fact more or less a Warwickshire village of about the period of the [Diamond Jubilee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen_Victoria#Diamond_Jubilee)
>
> <sup>*The Letters of J.R.R. Tolkien* 178: To Allen & Unwin. December 1955</sup>
>
> There is no special reference to England in the 'Shire' – except of course that as an Englishman brought up in an 'almost rural' village of Warwickshire on the edge of the prosperous bourgeoisie of Birmingham (about the time of the Diamond Jubilee!) I take my models like anyone else – from such 'life' as I know.
>
> <sup>*The letters of J.R.R. Tolkien* 181: To Michael Straight (draft). February 1956</sup>
>
> [I]f we drop the 'fiction' of long ago, 'The Shire' is based on rural England and not any other country in the world
>
> <sup>*The Letters of J.R.R. Tolkien* 190: To Rayner Unwin. July 1956</sup>
>
> **I am in fact a *Hobbit*** (in all but size). I like gardens, trees and unmechanized farmlands; I smoke a pipe, and **like good plain food (unrefrigerated), but detest French cooking**; I like, and even dare to wear in these dull days, ornamental waistcoats. I am **fond of mushrooms (out of a field)**
>
> <sup>*The Letters of J.R.R. Tolkien* 213: To Deborah Webster. October 1958</sup>
>
> The action of the story takes place in the North-west of 'Middle-earth', equivalent in latitude to the coastlands of Europe and the north shores of the Mediterranean. But this is not a purely 'Nordic' area in any sense. If Hobbiton and Rivendell are taken (as intended) to be at about the latitude of Oxford, then Minas Tirith, 600 miles south, is at about the latitude of Florence.
>
> <sup>*The Letters of J.R.R. Tolkien* 294: To Charlotte and Dennis Plimmer. February 1967</sup>

I would, however, question the assertion that "[hobbits] eat the way Americans seem to imagine the English to eat all day long." I would rather be inclined to argue that they eat the way an Englishman imagines the English of the late nineteenth century to eat.

Comment: Thank you. This is great. I knew only someone with access to this material would be able to answer, but I live in a third world country with no libraries, and bookshops only offering best-sellers in English.

Comment: I'd imagine Tolkien was in a pretty good position to understand how the English of the late 19th century ate :-)'

Comment: But what does any of it have to do with english breakfast?

Comment: @JBentley For an explanation of what I was trying to convey, please click on the link in the question. As I have already explained, when I was growing up, Tea was a meal.

Comment: @Gandalf Yeah I read through the comments and understood that you meant the meal known as "Tea". But that doesn't explain the "English Breakfast" part of your question, or how it relates to this answer. The link you gives describes an evening meal, whereas English Breakfast usually means [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_breakfast).

Comment: @JBentley to include the eggs, bacon, mushroom, bread, etc. Anyway, the remark was made as a subtle comment on what Americans seem to expect to eat when they go to England.

Comment: @JBentley I just clicked on your link, and that would seem to bolster my point, not undermine it

Comment: @Gandalf Ah ok, I think I see what the big misunderstanding is now. "English Breakfast" means all of those items (or some combination of those, and other items that are common for English Breakfast) *at the same time, in a single meal* and usually cooked in a particular way. Eggs with seed-cake, cold chicken and pickles, or mushrooms and bacon featuring in a casserole, don't have any relationship to English Breakfast. In the same way that a cheese on toast isn't really similar to a burger, even though both might feature bread and cheese.

Answer (score 4):

While in Ithilien, Sam knows how to skin, prepare and cook rabbit, and talks wistfully of potatoes. While potatoes can constitute some part of breakfast - some of the ways Sam talks about cooking them wouldn't be.

Rabbit is most certainly not eaten at breakfast nor tea.

As Jason Baker says - Hobbit food seems to be good old English country fare - but goes a beyond breakfast or tea.

Answer (score 0):

> Sam  . . . talks wistfully of potatoes. While potatoes can constitute some part of breakfast  . . .
>
> Hobbit food seems to be good old English country fare . . .
>
> [I]f we drop the 'fiction' of long ago . . .

You'd better.

Potatoes are American, specifically, South American. There weren't any potatoes in England until after 1588:

> "We think that the potato arrived . . . in Spain around 1570, and the . . .
> British isles between 1588 and 1593 . . . Sir Francis Drake or Thomas Harriot  are commonly credited with introducing potatoes into England."  -- WP

Europeans had to make do with carrots, turnips, and parsnips before then. If Middle Earth is Mediaeval England they shouldn't have potatoes.

(Please forgive any breach of protocol: this is my first post in this forum.)

Comment: Welcome to the site! The question is asking whether it's based on English meals from an era where High Tea was held, not from medieval times. The availability of potatoes is a good observation though, IIRC Tolkien edited out some other references to new world crops in later editions but kept potatoes.

Answer (score 0):

Considering repeated mentions of butter, honey, cream, and white bread being some of the most desirable and celebrated foodstuffs on the table, I think Tolkien's "menu" is more about what a (19th century) child would love to eat, rather than being specific about the type of food eaten by the English or Europeans in the past centuries.

Most food you mentioned in your question is *not* part of the English Breakfast, but would have been what the medieval/Victorian English people could eat.

Comment: Medieval/Victorian... just missing the intervening 500 year period?

Comment: @AndrewTice Well, and everything in-between too. Renaissance was more of a cultural and intellectual transformation, while peasants and commoners carried on living much as they did in medieval times.

Comment: ...like the Agricultural Revolution!